# How to set custom slide active in swiper in React js

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

i am working on swiper slide. i want to set custom slide active .
here is the code i tried.

```
<div className="swiper-container">
    <Swiper modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]} spaceBetween={50} slidesPerView={6} navigation
        loop={true} customActive={3} // centeredSlides={true} fade={true} slidesPerGroup={6} onSwiper={(swiper)=>
        console.log(swiper)}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}

        breakpoints={{
        992: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        slidesPerGroup: 4,
        },
        1113: {
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 40,
        slidesPerGroup: 5,
        },
        1350: {
        slidesPerView: 6,
        spaceBetween: 40,
        },
        1387: {
        slidesPerView: 6,
        spaceBetween: 52,
        },
        }}
        initialSlide={6},
        className="mySwiper">
        {itemList?.map((val, index) => {
        return (
        <span>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <button className="btn monthBtn defaultgrey w-100" style={{"background": "#941C26 !important"
                    }}>{val}</button>
            </SwiperSlide>
        </span>
        )
        })}
    </Swiper>
</div>
```

I tried "initialSlide" but it wont work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQLHB.png)

please see image, i want to active current month of the year, and when i click on another month it will  need to be active.

please see image, i want to active current month of the year, and when i click on another month it will  need to be active.